# 2 for 25 problem on Magento

Tags: magento, logic

OK I have a shop and would like to use shopping cart rules to add, it 2 products over a certain price are in the basket they are reduced to a set price.

2 T Shirts for £25

The T Shirts that qualify are £15.49 each.

They can the same t shirt or different t shirts.

However, when what i happening is that is any t shirt is added if there are 2 or more then discount is added.

I will attach screenshots but here is my logic:

If ALL of these conditions are TRUE:

If total quantity equals or greater than 2 for a sub selection of items in cart matching ALL of these conditions:
Price in cart is £15.49
Row total in cart equals or greater thyan £15.49

Discount applied £2.99

I hope this helps or if i could get guidance to offer 2 items for 25 on my store.

Thank You

Comment: what version are you using? 1.4.x have plenty of problems with Rules Mechanism, and 1.5 is not yet 100% working :-/

Answer (score 1):

not great but would work - use your SKU codes and only apply if those are in the cart.

Or you could get an attribute you dont use like weight, and make the Ts on sale 5 KG each, and then apply the discount only for 10KG & 20KG etc.  The other ts wont weight anything.

There are all sorts of crappy ways like this that you can sort out something that works